# why my texture is not smooth?

Tags: android, shader, opengl-es-2.0, texture2d

I want to show some object over the video preview. Let say it is a glass.
The png picture of this item is qualitative image 1024x1024.
I am using a mask to achive the result.
(Where mask is a binary image of an object)

I load texture in this way:

```
public static int loadTexture(final Context context, final String name){
    final int[] textureHandle = new int[1];

    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);

    if (textureHandle[0] != 0){

        // Read in the resource
        final Bitmap bitmap = getImageFromAssetsFile(context,name);

        // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);

        // Set filtering
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        // Recycle the bitmap, since its data has been loaded into OpenGL.
        bitmap.recycle();                       
    }

    if (textureHandle[0] == 0){
        throw new RuntimeException("Error loading texture.");
    }

    return textureHandle[0];
}
```

Here is my fragment shader

```
precision mediump float;

 varying mediump vec2 textureCoordinate;

 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture3;//glass shaped mask
 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture4;//my glass


 void main()
 {
      vec2 tempCoordinate = textureCoordinate;

      vec2 shapePos = vec2(1.4*tempCoordinate.x, 1.2*tempCoordinate.y-0.1);

      vec4 originColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, tempCoordinate);
      vec4 vMask = texture2D(inputImageTexture3, shapePos );
      vec4 butterfly = texture2D(inputImageTexture4, shapePos );
      if (vMask.r > 0.5)
          gl_FragColor = originColor*butterfly;
      else
          gl_FragColor = originColor;
 }
```

Image 1 (Nice looking smooth glass):

[image]

Image 2 (Shader result):

[image]

My question is how to produce less aliasing?